# Bind inner div to different knockoutJS view model with the same properties

Tags: knockout.js

I have an outer div that is bound to a view model with ProcessClick function and an inner div that is at runtime is bound to a different view model, but with the same function name for click. For some reason only an outer model's function also gets called before an inner VM's function does.

Markup:

```
<div id="max-outer">
   <span data-bind="click: BindInner">Bind Inner</span>
    <br/>
    <br/>
   <span data-bind="click: ProcessClick">Outer</span>
   <div id="max-inner">
      <span data-bind="click: ProcessClick">Inner</span>
       <br/>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function InnderModel() {
    self = this;

    self.ProcessClick = function () 
        {
            alert("Inner clicked");
        };
}

function OuterModel() {
    self = this;

    self.ProcessClick = function (){
            alert("Outer clicked");
        };

    self.BindInner = function () {
        ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById("max-inner"));
        ko.applyBindings(new InnderModel(), document.getElementById("max-inner"));
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new OuterModel(), document.getElementById("max-outer"));
```

Here is a fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/mpavlov/H2ZnV/8/

An idea is that clicking Bind inner and the clicking on Inner span would only show "Inner Clicked" alert, not both. Can this be achieved somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inner span will get bound the first time that `applyBindings` is called.

Calling `ko.cleanNode` does not actually remove any event handlers, so it will still have the original handler.

One technique that you could use is described in this tip on [knockmeout.net](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/quick-tip-skip-binding.html).

This allows you to identify an area that you want Knockout to skip binding.

You would add a simple custom binding on your section that you don't want to be bound originally:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.stopBinding = {
    init: function() {
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
```

Would be as shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Tmz8m/).